# WebForm Action - как остаться на странице

Tags: cgi, webforms

Моя вебформа вызывает cgi-script

```
    `<script> 
    function formSubmit(){
    form.action = "script.cgi"; 
    form.submit(); } 
    </script>`
```

В таком виде браузер исполняет скрипт и уходит со страницы. Нужно исполнить скрипт, но не уходить со страницы. Как это сделать?

Comment: Зачем куда то уходить когда есть AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my_button").click(function(event){
           $('#my_div').load('script.cgi');
        });
     });
  </script>

  <div id="my_div">
     TEST
  </div>        
  <input type="button" id="my_button" value="Load CGI Data" />
```

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, забыл подчеркнуть, что в скрипт надо передать данные с вебформы. Как этот скрипт дополнить?

Comment: Если из пушки по воробьям то можно так: $('#my_div').load('script.cgi?' + $('form').serialize());